# Lib Function that returns Rx.Observable doesn't inherit new Operators

Tags: javascript, webpack, rxjs

I'm developing a lib which has `RxJS` as a peer dependency and I'm bundling it using `webpack`. I configured webpack to exclude RxJS from the bundle, by setting `externals: [require("webpack-rxjs-externals")()]`.

In that lib, I've a function that returns an Observable. Something like:

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from'
import { map, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators'

export default function xpto(predicate) {
  return from(this).pipe(
    map(predicate),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
}
```

This function is then bound to an object that exposes an *observable hook* and it works as expected.

The problem occurs when I import this lib into another project, where I've also included RxJS and added a couple of *rx operators* by *prototype patching* them:

```js
import 'lib' // the one with xpto function
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'

// this breaks because although xpto returns an Observable
// it somehow wasn't patched with the filter operator
xpto(predicate).filter(whatever).subscribe(etc)
```

By patching the *Observable prototype*, I expected that the *Observable* instance that `xpto` returns, had the imported operators accessible through the prototype chain... but it doesn't.

Is it because how `xpto` function is bound? Is it something with how *webpack* is bundling this? What am I missing here?

Comment: What should `this` in `xpto` be bound to ?

Comment: @dev-null, I'm extending a Redux store object, so it's bound to that. The idea is to have a Observable selector of the Store's state.

Comment: It is hard to say if you made mistake in binding code as the code is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are at least two `Observable` instances. One inherits the operators and the other does not.

This can be fixed by adding the following on the `webpack.config.js` of the *app* where the *lib* is being included:

```js
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'rxjs/Observable': path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/rxjs/Observable')
    }
}
```